# Two modules are isomorphic in the stable module category iff they are projectively equivalent

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, projective-module

Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring. Let ${\text{mod-}R}$ be the category of finitely generated right $R$-modules. Let $\underline{\text{mod-}R}$ be the stable module category, with the same objects as ${\text{mod-}R}$ and morphisms given by $\text{Hom}_R(M,N)/ \hspace{-3pt} \sim$, where $f \sim g$ iff $f-g$ factors through a projective module.

We say that two $R$-modules $M,N$ are projectively equivalent iff there exist finitely generated projective modules $P,Q$ with $M \oplus P \cong N \oplus Q$ in ${\text{mod-}R}$.

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $M,N$ be finitely generated $R$-modules. Then $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic in the stable module category iff they are projectively equivalent.

I know this to be true, but I want to prove it by constructing specific maps. So far I've only attempted the forward implication. So suppose that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic in the stable module category, so there exist $f : M \to N$ and $g: N \to M$ with 
\begin{gather*}
gf - \text{id}_M = \phi : M \xrightarrow{\phi_1} P \xrightarrow{\phi_2} M \\
fg - \text{id}_N = \psi : N \xrightarrow{\psi_1} Q \xrightarrow{\psi_2} N.
\end{gather*}
I then want to construct maps $\theta:M \oplus P \to N \oplus Q$ and $\lambda:N \oplus Q \to M \oplus P$ (or perhaps the maps should go between $M \oplus Q$ and $N \oplus P$...?) which are mutual inverses. However, playing around with these maps hasn't led me anywhere. In fact one major issue is that I can't see how I would be obtain the identity in the second component of $\lambda \theta$, and I suspect that I actually need to construct some new maps using the projectivity of $P$ and $Q$.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: The other direction is probably more straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is not going to work unless you're careful about the choice of the projective modules $P$ and $Q$ through which $gf-\text{id}_M$ and $fg-\text{id}_N$ factor. Indeed, you could replace $P$ by $P\oplus P'$ for any projective module $P'$, changing the isomorphism type of $M\oplus P$.

Instead, use the fact that $gf-\text{id}_M$ factor through a projective $P$ to construct maps $M\stackrel{f'}{\to}N\oplus P\stackrel{g'}{\to}M$ such that $g'f'=\text{id}_M$ and $f'g'-\text{id}_{N\oplus P}$ factors through a projective, so that $M\oplus\operatorname{ker}(g')\cong N\oplus P$, and then (using the fact that $f'g'-\text{id}_{N\oplus P}$ factors through a projective) that $\operatorname{ker}(g')$ is projective.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Just to check, we define $f'(m) = (f(m), \phi_1(m))$ and $g'(n,p) = g(n) - \phi_2(p)$. Then $f'g' - \text{id}_{N \oplus P}$ factors through $Q \oplus P \oplus P$ via $\theta_1(n,p) = (\psi_1(n), \hspace{3pt} p, \hspace{3pt} \phi_1 \circ g (n) - \phi_1 \circ \phi_2 (p))$ and $\theta_2(q,p_1,p_2) = (\psi_2(q) - f \circ \phi_2(p_1), \hspace{3pt} p_2 - p_1)$. Is there perhaps a simpler module which it factors through?

Comment: @Simon That looks about right. In general I don't think there's a simpler module because to show that $f'g'-\text{id}_{N\oplus P}$ factors through a projective, you need a copy of $Q$ to kill the composition $N\to M\to N$, a copy of $P$ to kill the composition $P\to M\to N\oplus P$, and another copy of $P$ to kill the composition $N\to M\to P$.

Comment: Why does the fact that f'g'-id factors through a projective imply that Kerg' is projective? Is an obvious thing I am missing?

Comment: @Constantinos $\ker(g')$ is a direct summand of $N\oplus P$, and (writing $\iota$ and $\pi$ for the inclusion and projection maps), $\pi\circ(\text{id}_{N\oplus P}-f'g')\circ\iota=\text{id}_{\ker(g')}$. Since $\text{id}_{N\oplus P}-f'g'$ factors through a projective, so does $\text{id}_{\ker(g')}$, and so $\ker(g')$ is a direct summand of a projective, and therefore projective.